# Why isn't my flex item aligning in the center?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am trying to center a red box in the middle of the page.

I have set the flex container to 100% in height, and have also set the html,body to 100%, and it still does not align center.

Can anyone please help me understand why its not working? Thanks!

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
    <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `justify-content` to align flex items on the *main axis*.

You use `align-items` to align flex items on the *cross axis*.

Since your flex container is `flex-direction: column`:

- the main axis is vertical, and
- the cross axis is horizontal.

`justify-content: center` is working fine.

You just need to add `align-items: center`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;       /* centers flex items vertically, in this case */
  align-items: center; /* NEW */ /* centers flex items horizontally, in this case */
  height: 100%
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

Here's a more detailed explanation:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add align-items to .flex-container

```
align-items: center;
```

See here for an example https://jsfiddle.net/x9gyheo6/1/